# Getting article type information [New Result / Confirmatory Result / Contradictory Result] from bioRxiv

Tags: biorxiv

The bioRxiv advanced search form lets one find articles by their type. Following are the three types:

- New Result
- Confirmatory Result
- Contradictory Result

An RSS feed is also available here:
http://biorxiv.org/content/alertsrss

But I could not find any field in the entries for 'article type'. Is there a programmatic way of querying this information that I am missing ?

I could scrape the specific article page itself for this info. But that would not be too efficient. If anyone knows an API / RSS way of obtaining this information and shares it, it might be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the few XML in bioRxiv's RSS feeds, it looks like the information that you are looking for simply is not included in their schema at present.  Thus, I would say that your only options are:

1. Screen-scraping
2. Asking for them to upgrade their feeds